# Plotting graphs from a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, graph, plot, matlab-figure

I have this for loop

```
for mass = 1:.1:4
theta = 60;
Fw = [0 -9.8*mass 0];
Rw = [ 0.2*cosd(theta) 0.2*sind(theta) 0];
Mw = cross(Rw,Fw);
Fjrf = [30 50 0];
Rjrf = [0.4*cosd(theta) 0.4*sind(theta) 0];
Mjrf = cross(Rjrf,Fjrf);
alpha = 5;
Ialpha = [0 0 alpha*(0.02+mass*0.2^2)];
Ms = Ialpha - Mjrf - Mw;
omega = [0 0 pi];
alphav = [0 0 5];
anorm = ([-cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0]*(norm(omega))^2);
atang = cross(Rjrf,alphav);
a = anorm + atang;
Fmuscle = norm(mass*a - Fjrf - Fw)
mass
plot(mass,Fmuscle)'
hold on
end
```

Where in the end the output is just various values of Fmuscle, that correspond to values of mass varrying from 1 to 4 at intervals of .1.  I am trying to plot all these values on a graph (mass =x and Fmuscle = y) but I cannot figure out how to generate this.
With the code I have above I simply get an empty graph, even though I get all the right variables. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This what you want?

```
i = 0;  %set initial index
clear x y;  %clear these variables
for mass = 1:.1:4
  i = i + 1;  %increment index
  theta = 60;
  Fw = [0 -9.8*mass 0];
  Rw = [ 0.2*cosd(theta) 0.2*sind(theta) 0];
  Mw = cross(Rw,Fw);
  Fjrf = [30 50 0];
  Rjrf = [0.4*cosd(theta) 0.4*sind(theta) 0];
  Mjrf = cross(Rjrf,Fjrf);
  alpha = 5;
  Ialpha = [0 0 alpha*(0.02+mass*0.2^2)];
  Ms = Ialpha - Mjrf - Mw;
  omega = [0 0 pi];
  alphav = [0 0 5];
  anorm = ([-cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0]*(norm(omega))^2);
  atang = cross(Rjrf,alphav);
  a = anorm + atang;
  Fmuscle = norm(mass*a - Fjrf - Fw);
  x(i) = mass;    % set the appropriate row of x vector
  y(i) = Fmuscle; % same for y
end
plot(x, y);
```